# Convert the nested array to single array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have array format like this

```js
response = {
  "data": [{
      "districts": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "sikkim district",
        "statistics": [{
            "food saftey": 2,
            "food ": 2,
            "air pollution": 0
          },
          {
            "food saftey": 5,
            "food ": 6,
            "air pollution": 7
          },
          {
            "food saftey": 7,
            "food ": 6,
            "air pollution": 0
          }
        ]
      }]
    },
    {
      "districts": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bhojpur",
        "statistics": [{
            "food saftey": 1,
            "food ": 1,
            "air pollution": 1
          },
          {
            "food saftey": 5,
            "food ": 7,
            "air pollution": 6
          },
        ]
      }]
    }
  ],

}
```

and the required format is

```js
{
  "data": [{
      "district": "sikkim district",
      "food saftey": 2,
      "food ": 2,
      "air pollution": 0
    },
    {
      "district": "sikkim district",
      "food saftey": 5,
      "food ": 6,
      "air pollution": 7
    },
    "district": "sikkim district",
    {
      "food saftey": 7,
      "food ": 6,
      "air pollution": 0
    },
    {
      "district": "Bhojpur",
      "food saftey": 1,
      "food ": 1,
      "air pollution": 1
    },
    {
      "district": "Bhojpur",
      "food saftey": 5,
      "food ": 7,
      "air pollution": 6
    },

  ],
```

The array format is in dynamic which keeps changing except the district and the district has to be at the beginning of the array.

Html should be in this format

```html
<table id="dataTable1" class="table table-condensed table-bordered custom-col-auto row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="custom-header-col" *ngFor="let column of columns">
        {{column}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of reportsComplainTypeData">
      <td class="custom-body-col" *ngFor='let column of columns'>{{data.data[column]| json}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how the html should look like as the data is dynamic and keeps changing other then district

This is what i have tried to rearrange the array

```js
response.data.filter(item => {
  item.districts.filter(item1 => {
    item1.statistics.map(data => {
      value.push({
        districts: item1.name,
        data
      })
    })
  })
})
value.map(item => {
  item.data.districts = item.districts
  delete item.districts;
})
```

Comment: What is your question? And what have to done so far?

Comment: i need the nested array in single array

Comment: Your JSON is full of arrays that in this example only have one object. Why are those arrays? Can there be more than one object?

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: you can check my code

Comment: i have added what i have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pull out the wanted properties and assemble a new objects for each level.

```js
var response = { data: [{ districts: [{ id: 1, name: "sikkim district", statistics: [{ "food saftey": 2, "food ": 2, "air pollution": 0 }, { "food saftey": 5, "food ": 6, "air pollution": 7 }, { "food saftey": 7, "food ": 6, "air pollution": 0 }] }] }, { districts: [{ id: 2, name: "Bhojpur", statistics: [{ "food saftey": 1, "food ": 1, "air pollution": 1 }, { "food saftey": 5, "food ": 7, "air pollution": 6 }] }] }] };
     
response.data = response.data.reduce((r, { districts }) =>
    districts.reduce((s, { name: district, statistics }) =>
        statistics.reduce((t, statistic) => [...t, { district, ...statistic }], s),
        r
    ),
    []
);

console.log(response.data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i have tried somthing like this the issue is i need the district at the beginning of the array buts its comming at the last

Comment: with this approach as well?

Comment: hey its working thank you so much and district is at beginning

Comment: but this is not working if statistics array has two objects for same district

Comment: maybe, do you have some data and the wanted result? what should happen with more of the same in this case?

Comment: but as the data is the for  reference purpose i just now check with another object but the result its giving if for only first object

Comment: but if i don't know what should happen, how can i give an answer? please add missing parts to the question.

Comment: do you have only one element in `districts`? or could you have more than one?

Comment: can have more element

Comment: what does this ...t means? i have never used

Comment: it is the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for getting the elements of an array (or any other iterable object) as paramerters.

Answer (score 0):

Use some format function:

```
function formatResponse(response) {
  return response.data.map((item) => {
    let district = item.districts[0];
    obj = {name: district.name};
    return Object.assign(obj, district.statistics[0]);
  });
}
```